# php search with latin basic, but return results with diactrics

Tags: php, symfony, utf-8, doctrine

I'm running into a complicated situation here, and I'm hoping for a push in the right direction.

I need to allow Basic Latin searches to bring back results with diacritics.  This is further complicated by the fact that the data is stored with HTML instead of pure ASCII.  I have been making some progress, but have come across two problems.

First: I'm able to do a partial conversion of the data into something marginally useful, using something like this:

```
$string = 'V&eacute;ra';
$converted = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');
$translit = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $converted);
echo $translit;
```

This brings back this result: `V'era`  This is a start but what I really need is `Vera`.  I can do a preg_replace on resulting string, but is there a way of just bringing it back without the hyphen? This is only one example; there are a lot more diacritics in the database (e.g. `&ntilde;` and more).  I feel like this has been addressed before (e.g. [iconv returns strange results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915040/iconv-returns-strange-results)), but there don't appear to be any solutions listed.

**Bigger Problem:** I need to convert a string such as `Vera` and be able to bring back results with `V&eacute;ra`.  as well as results of `Vera`.  However I believe I need to get problem 1 solved first before I can get to this point.

I'm thinking something like if ($translit) { return $string} but I'm a bit unsure of how to handle this.

All help appreciated.

**Edit:**  I'm thinking this might be done easier directly in the database, however I'm running into issues with DQL.   I know that there are ways with doing it in SQL with a stored procedure, but with limited access to the database, I'm open any suggestions for dealing with this in Doctrine

**Okay, so maybe I'm making this too difficult**

All I need is a way of finding entries that have been HTML encoded in the database without having to search with either the specific encoding but *also* without the diacritic itself.  If I search for `Jose`, it should bring up anything in the database labeled as `Jos&eacute;`

Comment: Which type of SQL database are you using?

Comment: @ahmetson It's a mysql database, but all of the connections are through Doctrine/DQL.  I know I could probably handle this through a stored procedure, but Ops doesn't seem to like this.  I may have to take this approach but I'd like to explore other options first

Comment: May this help you - https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,246527,246527

Comment: @AhmedGinani thanks, I did see that one.  It does look promising;  do you know if this (or an equivalent) would work in DQL?  I may not have the ability to store a procedure in this particular DB.

Comment: Are they always named entities and always `acute`, `grave`, or `tilde`? The input is always ascii, or that too can be accented and/or entitized?

Answer (score 1):

Preface: It's not quite clear whether the data to search is already in the database or whether you're just taking advantage of the fact that the database has logic for character comparisons. I'm going to assume that the data source is the DB.

The fact that you're trying to search html raises the question of whether you really want to search HTML or in fact want to search the user-visible text in HTML and strip html tags (What if there is a diacritic in a tag attribute? What if a word is broken with an empty `<span>`? Should it match? What if it was broken with a `<br>`?)

---

MySQL has the notion of both *character sets* (how characters are encoded) and *collations* (how characters are compared)

Relevant Documentation:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-mysql.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-sets.html

Assuming your mysql client/terminal is correctly set for UTF8 encoding, then the following demonstrates the effect of overriding the collation (using ß as particularly interesting example)

```
> SET NAMES 'utf8';
> SELECT
   'ß',
   'ss',
   'ß' = 'ss' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci AS ss_unicode,
   'ß' = 'ss' COLLATE utf8_general_ci AS ss_general,
   'ß' = 's' COLLATE utf8_general_ci AS s_general;
+----+----+------------+------------+-----------+
| ß  | ss | ss_unicode | ss_general | s_general |
+----+----+------------+------------+-----------+
| ß  | ss |          1 |          0 |         1 |
+----+----+------------+------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note: `general` is the faster but not-strictly-correct version of the `unicode` collation -- but even that is wrong if you speak turkish (see: [dotted uppercase i](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I))

I would save decoded html in the database and search on this making sure that the collation is set correctly.

- Confirm that the table/column collation is correct using `SHOW CREATE TABLE xxx`. Change it manually (`ALTER TABLE ...`), or use doctrine annotations as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15984862/6653190) & use doctrine migrations to update (and confirm afterwards with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` that your version of doctrine respects collation)
- Confirm that doctrine is [configured](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url) to use utf8 encoding.

If you just need to override the collation for one particular query (eg you don't have permission to change the DB structure or it will break other code):

- If you need to map to a doctrine ORM object, use [NativeQuery](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) and add `COLLATE` overrides as per the example above.
- If you just want the record ID & field then you can use a direct [query](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#api) bypassing the ORM with a `COLLATE` override

Comment: I should have mentioned, I can't alter the database.

Comment: You can't alter the database structure, or its contents? (or both?) Are additions allowed? (eg new column or new user defined function?

Comment: The structure (as in adding in stored procedures, though I may be able to revisit this).  I can add changes to the schema if necessary  (so yes to new columns)

Comment: I can't see any vaguely performant way of doing this without adding a precalculated column (or cache table if you prefer) of html decoded to utf8; PHP has its own Collator class from 5.3 but to use it you would have to pull back all the DB results and compare them in PHP which would be quite slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEX_REPLACE function to strip diactrics in Database, while requesting. Mysql database has no built-in regex_replace function, but you can use User Defined Library, or change library to MariaDB. MariaDB based on Mysql (Migrating data to MariaDB will be easy).

Then in MariaDB you can use queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE 'jose' = REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '(&[A-Za-z]*;)', '')
// another variant with PHP variable
SELECT `table`.name FROM `table` WHERE $search = REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '(&[A-Za-z]*;)', '')
```

Even phpMyAdmin supports MariaDB. I tested my query on Demo page. It worked pretty well:
[image]

---

Or if you want to stay on MySql, add this UDFs:

https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg

Comment: As mentioned, this is a large pre-existing DB that cannot be modified in this fashion.